# Changed Database Default Locations now I can't create database

Tags: database, sql-server-express

I changed database default locations using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and now, when I start my application, which should create a database using Visual Studio, so I have admin rights it says this:

```
Directory lookup for the file "D:\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseNameE.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

I am 100% that the path is right and the folders exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by looking at security properties of default folder of database default locations. It had mssql$sqlexpress as user with full control. So I added it to security properties of the new folder of database default locations.